# When creating invoice the order status is always Suspected Fraud

Tags: magento2, order-status

My order status are like this:

[image]

What's wrong with it?

happens with all kinds of payment methods!

Magento see. 2.2.11

Comment: Have you used an extension which changes rounding behaviour?

Comment: No i dont think so! But it seems that those status are not well configured, what do u think?

Comment: You've got default statues https://i.snipboard.io/eJk0lf.jpg

Comment: So does it mean that it is well configured? So where's the problem? There should not be Suspected Fraud in a bank transfer :/ it's not normal